# How to validate a column value in a csv file imported, and give validation error if not present in django

Tags: python, django, csv

Here I'm trying to get the individual column value from the uploaded file and trying to retrieve a validation for a column not present in the csv checking if the file uploaded is a csv or not if not give a error saying unsupported file format, if a csv then check for the column inside and if any of the column is missing give a validation saying " * " column is not present.

here is a part of csv file

```
time,amplitude
0,0.73904
0.02441,1.2372
0.04883,1.0019
0.07324,0.50924
0.09766,-0.603
0.12207,-1.6674
0.14648,-1.5332
0.1709,-0.85486
0.19531,0.3971
0.21973,1.3604
0.24414,1.8384
```

my **validation.py** file

```
def validate_file(value):

    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
    valid_extentions = ['.csv']
    if ext.lower() in valid_extentions:
        return value
    else:
        raise ValidationError(u'Unsupported file extention. please upload a .csv file. ')
    csv = pd.read_csv(value, header=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist()
    first = csv.index('time')
    second = csv.index('amplitude')
    if first != 0:
        raise ValidationError(u'Missing time value data')
    elif second != 1:
        raise ValidationError(u'Missing Amplitude value data')
    else:
        return value
```

**forms.py**

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = SourceFile
        fields = ('file',)


    def clean_csv_file(self):
        upload = self.cleaned_data['file']

        if upload:
            filename = upload.name
            if filename.endswith(settings.FILE_UPLOAD_TYPE):
                csv = pd.read_csv(upload.name)
                

                if csv.isnull().any()['time']:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(u'Missing time value data')

                elif csv.isnull().any()['amplitude']:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(u'Missing amplitude value data')
                
                else:
                    return upload

        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please upload a .csv extention files only")
        
        return upload

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UploadFileForm, self, clean)
    upload = cleaned_data.get('file')
    return upload
```

**views.py**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_uploaded = form.save(commit=False)
            # file = UploadFileForm()
            form.save()
            return redirect('Index')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render (request, 'visual/upload.html', {'form' : form})
```

I've used this but not getting any validation even tho I give a csv without a time column value, please be free to ask for any requirements in the question, thank you in advance.

Comment: `if csv.isnull().any()['time']: raise Error`?

Comment: it gives this error 'list' object has no attribute 'isnull' @Ersain

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you converted the dataframe into list. Then just `csv = pd.read_csv(value.name)` and `if csv.isnull().any()['time']: raise ValidationError(...)`

Comment: @Ersain sorry to say that this is popping up another `FileNotFound` error, ill be updating the question with my view file and forms file please have a peek into it, it would be a great help, thank you!!